# GOLANG with LiteIDE: I can't see "Hello World!" in Build Output window

Tags: go

I have install go lang on windows 8 64bit by following this tutorial http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/other-languages/6600-a-programmers-guide-to-go-with-liteide-part-1.html

So, I create a 'Go1 command project' with name 'hello' and when Build+Run (Ctrl+R) in the Build Output window can't see the "Hello World!"

**This is what i get in the output:**

```
Current environment change id "win64-user"
C:/go/bin/go.exe env [c:\go]
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCHAR=6
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=c:\go
set GOTOOLDIR=c:\go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set TERM=dumb
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-g -O2 -m64 -mthreads
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
Command exited with code 0.
c:/go/bin/go.exe build  [C:/Go/src/hello]
Success: process exited with code 0.
C:/Go/src/hello/hello.exe  [C:/Go/src/hello]
Success: process exited with code 0.
```

Screenshot: http://s8.postimg.org/rpodnumid/golang_screenshot.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the other output windows? I do not use LiteIDE but I guess the build window is just for build-related stuff, not execution one.

Comment: Not yet, how you execute your files or trace your code?

Comment: I usually use go run / go build in the commandline.

However, I gave a try to LiteIDE, I am able to see the "Hello world!" traces on my side and they are in the "Build Output" window so I do not really understand why you do not have them on your side. :/

You can try running your executable using a commandline: just go in the C:/Go/src/hello/ directory and run hello.exe

Comment: I gave a try to 'go run main.go' in commandline and returns nothing, screenshot: http://s30.postimg.org/5el2t9z41/cmd_golang.jpg

Comment: "*commandline and returns nothing*" - In that case I'd suspect an issue with the code itself. Have you typed it in or copypasted?

Comment: The 'hello world' code it comes from the LiteIDE while you create new 'Go1 command project', see the code in this screenshot: s8.postimg.org/rpodnumid/golang_screenshot.jpg

Comment: I tried to create the "Go1 command project" like you did, it does come with a sample hello world in it and the code is perfectly fine, it outputs the text on my side. :/

Comment: Take a look of this link, this is my problem after all, but with Comodo Antivirus instead of Bitdefender http://forum.bitdefender.com/index.php?showtopic=45169 I removed the Comodo free internet security from my system and now GOLANG-LiteIDE works fine (I can see all the text in Output)! It was the Sandbox tool of Comodo and I was having the alerts hidden (ahh my bad) in the Sandbox settings.

Am wondering how to set Sandbox settings, to NOT sandbox files that GOLANG is creating by compilers. If anyone know-how please let me know.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Found this Comodo->Advanced->Defense+->Behavior Blocker->Exclusions->Add->Browse.. select C:\Go folder and problems are gone! Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @superstar Could you please answer your own question and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this tutorial missed pretty tricky part with  MS Windows OS. 
You have to setup enviromental variables first in your OS.
1. Go to System Settings
2. Additional settings
3. Environment settings
4. Then please use this tutorial and setup OS enviroment variable accordigly.

If everything's done right.

```
go env
```

Will return GOPATH=YOUR_FOLDER_WITH_LITE_IDE_APPS

you will easily launch from any directory in command line,
lite IDE will also work after catching GOPATH variable.

Good luck !